# Java HashMap or IdentityHashMap

Tags: java

There are some cases that the key objects used in map do not override hashCode() and equals() from Object, for examples, use a socket Connection or java.lang.Class as keys.

1. Is there any potential defect to use these objects as keys in a HashMap?
2. Should I use IdentityHashMap in these cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `equals()` and `hashCode()` are not overridden on key objects, HashMap and IdentityHashMap should have the same semantics. The default equals() implementation uses reference semantics, and the default `hashCode()` is the system identity hash code of the object.

This is only harmful in cases where different instances of an object can be considered logically equal. For example, you would not want to use IdentityHashMap if your keys were:

```
new Integer(1)
```

and

```
new Integer(1)
```

Since these are technically different instances of the Integer class. (You should really be using `Integer.valueOf(1)`, but that's getting off-topic.)

`Class` as keys should be okay, except in very special circumstances (for example, the hibernate ORM library generates subclasses of your classes at runtime in order to implement a proxy.) As a developer I would be skeptical of code which stores `Connection` objects in a Map as keys (maybe you should be using a connection pool, if you are managing database connections?). Whether or not they will work depends on the implementation (since Connection is just an interface).

Also, it's important to note that HashMap expects the `equals()` and `hashCode()` determination to remain constant. In particular, if you implement some custom `hashCode()` which uses mutable fields on the key object, changing a key field may make the key get 'lost' in the wrong hashtable bucket of the HashMap. In these cases, you may be able to use IdentityHashMap (depending on the object and your particular use case), or you might just need a different `equals()/hashCode()` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

From a mobile code security point of view, there are situations where using `IdentityHashMap` or similar becomes necessary. Malicious implementations of non-`final` key classes can override `hashCode` and `equals` to be malicious. They can, for instance, claim equality to different instances, acquire a reference to other instances they are compared to, etc. I suggest breaking with standard practice by staying safe and using `IdentityHashMap` where you want identity semantics. There rarely is a good reason to changing the meaning of equality in a subclass where the superclass is already being compared. I guess the most likely scenario is  a broken, non-symmetric proxy.

The implementation of `IdentityHashMap` is quite different than `HashMap`. It uses linear probing rather than `Entry` objects as links in a chain. This leads to a slight reduction in the number of objects, although a pretty small difference in total memory use. I don't have any good performance statistics I can cite. There used to be a performance difference between using (non-overridden) `Object.hashCode` and `System.identityHashCode`, but that got cleared up a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

In situation you describes, the behaviors of HashMap and IdentityHashMap is identical.

On the contrast to this, if keys overrides equals() and hashCode(), behaviors of two maps are different.

see java.util.IdentityHashMap's javadoc below.

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values). In other words, in an IdentityHashMap, two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==k2). (In normal Map implementations (like HashMap) two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal if and only if (k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2)).)

In summary, my answer is that:

1. Is there any potential defect to use these objects as keys in a HashMap?
   --> **No**
2. Should I use IdentityHashMap in these cases? --> **No**

Answer (score 1):

While there's no theoretical problem, you should avoid `IdentityHashMap` unless you have an explicit reason to use it.  It provides no appreciable performance or other benefit in the general case, and when you inevitably start introducing objects into the map that *do* override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, you'll end up with subtle, hard-to-diagnose bugs.

If you think you need `IdentityHashMap` for performance reasons, use a profiler to confirm that suspicion before you make the switch.  My guess is you'll find plenty of other opportunities for optimization that are both safer and make a bigger difference.

Comment: Nitpick - in the general case `==` and `System.identityHashCode` **are** faster than typical overloaded `equals` and `hashCode` methods.  But I agree that that's generally not a good reason to use `IdentityHashMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: @Stephen C: fair enough -- I've added a disclaimer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only problem with a hashmap with bad keys, would be with very big hashmaps- your keys could be very bad and you get o(n) retrieval time, instead of o(1). If it does break anything else, I would be interested to hear about it though :)

Comment: you mean bad hashCode methods don't you?